# VBS Script remove read only and add read only

Tags: vbscript

I am completely new to VBS script.

I have managed to open my excel sheet and write "New data" and save it again.
This code:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\g46973\Desktop\test.xlsx")
set xlSht = objExcel.activesheet


objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
xlSht.Cells(2, 2) = "New Data"

objWorkbook.Save
 objWorkBook.Close SaveChanges=True

 ObjExcel.Quit
```

The problem is my excel workbook is Read-only (I want it to stay that way). Then i run my code I want to remove read only from my excel workbook. Run the code above, and then again add Read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Set book = myOBJ.WorkBooks.Open(FileName:="mybook.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: Set book = myOBJ.WorkBooks.Open(FileName:="mybook.xls", ReadOnly:=False)

Comment: With your code
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\g46973\Desktop\test.xlsx",, FALSE) 

Does not open my readonly workbook as edit-able. Because i can see it does not save my text:"New data", I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\g46973\Desktop\test.xlsx",‌​,True
```

This one works for me.